# Getting the percentage of used space and used inodes in a mount

Tags: linux, go, filesystems, storage, disk

I need to calculate the percentage of used space and used inodes for a mount path (e.g. `/mnt/mycustommount`) in Go.

This is my attempt:

```golang
var statFsOutput unix.Statfs_t

err := unix.Statfs(mount_path, &statFsOutput)
if err != nil {
    return err
}

totalBlockCount := statFsOutput.Blocks // Total data blocks in filesystem
freeSystemBlockCount = statFsOutput.Bfree // Free blocks in filesystem
freeUserBlockCount = statFsOutput.Bavail // Free blocks available to unprivileged user
```

Now the proportion I need would be something like this:

```
x : 100 = (totalBlockCount - free[which?]BlockCount) : totalBlockCount
```

i.e. `x : 100 = usedBlockCount : totalBlockCount` . But I don't understand the difference between `Bfree` and `Bavail` (what's 'unprivileged' user go to do with filesystem blocks?).

For inodes my attempt:

```golang
totalInodeCount = statFsOutput.Files
freeInodeCount = statFsOutput.Ffree
// so now the proportion is
// x : 100 = (totalInodeCount - freeInodeCount) : totalInodeCount
```

How to get the percentage for used storage?
And is the inodes calculation I did correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your comment expression isn't valid Go, so I can't really interpret it without guessing.  *With* guessing, I interpret it as correct, but have I guessed what you actually mean, or merely what I *think* you mean?  In other words, without showing actual *code*, I can only imagine what your final *code* will be.  If the code I imagine isn't the actual code, the correctness of the code I imagine you will write is irrelevant.

That aside, I *can* answer your question here:

> (what's 'unprivileged' user go to do with filesystem blocks?)

The [Linux `statfs` call](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/statfs.2.html) uses the same fields as 4.4BSD.  The default 4.4BSD file system (the one called the "fast file system") uses a blocks-with-fragmentation approach to allocate blocks in a sort of [stochastic](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/stochastic) manner.  This allocation process works very well on an *empty* file system, and continues to work well, without extreme slowdown, on somewhat-full file systems.  Computerized modeling of its behavior, however, showed pathological slowdowns (amounting to linear search, more or less) were possible if the block usage exceeded somewhere around 90%.

(Later, analysis of real file systems found that the slowdowns generally did not hit until the block usage exceeded 95%.  But the idea of a 10% "reserve" was pretty well established by then.)

Hence, if a then-popular large-size disk drive of 400 MB<sup>1</sup> gave 10% for inodes and another 10% for reserved blocks, that meant that ordinary users could allocate about 320 MB of file data.  At that point the drive was "100% full", but it could go to 111% by using up the remaining blocks.  Those blocks were reserved to the super-user though.

These days, instead of a "super user", one can have a [*capability*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Capability-based_security) that can be granted or revoked.  However, these days we don't use the same file systems either.  So there may be no difference between `bfree` and `bavail` on your system.

---

<sup>1</sup>Yes, [the 400 MB Fujitsu Eagle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fujitsu_Eagle) was a large (in multiple senses: it used a 19 inch rack mount setup) drive back then.  People are spoiled today with their multi-terabyte SSDs.